# Difference between typescript declaration of type

Tags: typescript

I have this hash:

```
const COLOR_TO_VALUE: {[key: string]: number} = {
    black: 0,
    brown: 1,
...
}
```

If I want to reference the keys in a function such as:

```
export function decodedResistorValue(colorBands: Color[]){
...
}
```

What is the difference between:

```
type Color = typeof COLOR_TO_VALUE[string];
```

and

```
type Color = keyof typeof COLOR_TO_VALUE;
```

Comment: as far as I understand it on second it'll take every props, on first only those that are string. I'm like 50% sure on that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first syntax will get the type of all the values for which the keys are `string`. In this case this is `number`.

The second one will get the type of all the keys for the type of `COLOR_TO_VALUE`. You may expect that to be `string`, but because of how objects work in JS, you may access it using string index or numeric one, the type is actually `number | string`.

But I think that what you actually want is to end up with this type `black | brown`. You can do this by letting TS infer the type and use `keyof typeof`. Something like this:

```
const COLOR_TO_VALUE = {
    black: "0",
    brown: "1",
}

type Color = keyof typeof COLOR_TO_VALUE;
```